# Item Collection option for a User Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties, controls

As you can see in the pic below, for a ListView Control you can add Items using the Properties pane.

How do I enable this kind of stuff for my UserControl?

I'm not getting anything when I search Google, but I'm probably not using the correct terms.

Does anybody know?

Thanks

[image: Visual Studio Properties Pane]

Comment: you want to pass Collection to usercontrol.

Comment: I tried searching for "pass Collection to usercontrol" and a few variations, but only found references to WPF and Web Apps, but this is for winforms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a class that defines the object type that the collection ids composed of.  A listView has ListViewItem objects.  A TabControl has TabPage objects.  Your control has  objects which are defined by you.  Let's call it MyItemType.

You also need a wraper class for the collection.  A simple implementation is shown below.

```
public class MyItemTypeCollection : CollectionBase
{

    public MyItemType this[int Index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (MyItemType)List[Index];
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(MyItemType itemType)
    {
        return List.Contains(itemType);
    }

    public int Add(MyItemType itemType)
    {
        return List.Add(itemType);
    }

    public void Remove(MyItemType itemType)
    {
        List.Remove(itemType);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, MyItemType itemType)
    {
        List.Insert(index, itemType);
    }

    public int IndexOf(MyItemType itemType)
    {
       return List.IndexOf(itemType);
    }
}
```

Finally you need to add a member variable for the collection to your user control and decorate it properly:

```
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public MyItemTypeCollection MyItemTypes
    {
        get { return _myItemTypeCollection; }
    }
```

and you now have a simple interface that allows you to browse and edit the collection.  Leaves a lot to be desired still but to do more you will have to learn about custom designers which can be difficult to understand and implement.

Comment: Wow, that was incredibly easy to understand. Thanks for your help and time! :)

Comment: @Sisyphus can you give an example of MyItemType please?