# Create custom User Control Items

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, user-controls, items

I want to make my own DropDown (Combobox) with visual `Items`, which contain a `Picture`, a `Name` and a `Comment`. The problem is if I add an `Item` in the properties everything is okay, visual studio adds the code in the form designer, but the item isn't displayed.

The Item Collection Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace List_Item_Test
     {
       public partial class My_Item : CollectionBase
        {
        public Items this[int Index]
        {
            get
            {
                return (Items)List[Index];
            }
        }

        public bool Contains(Items itemType)
        {
            return List.Contains(itemType);
        }

        public int Add(Items itemType)
        {
        //i think hier something is missing???
            return List.Add(itemType);
        }

    public void Remove(Items itemType)
    {
        List.Remove(itemType);
    }

public void Insert(int index, Items itemType)
    {
        List.Insert(index, itemType);
    }

        public int IndexOf(Items itemType)
        {
            return List.IndexOf(itemType);
        }

    }
}
```

The Item Container Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace List_Item_Test
{
    public partial class Item_Container : UserControl
    {
        public Item_Container()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        My_Item hallo = new My_Item();

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public My_Item MyItemTypes
        {
            get { return hallo; }
            set
            {
                Items hallo1 = new Items();
                hallo1.SetBounds(0, 10 + /*hallo.Count - 1 **/ 50, Width, 50);
                this.Controls.Add(hallo1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these the only code you have? Where is the part of the code that adds the pictures into the combobox items? And where's the part of the code that adds the items into the combobox? (Your `MyItemTypes` property is never called, so its setter code never gets run.)

Comment: the item is my UserControl and i want to create my own combobox like component where the items are listed.

(like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000331/item-collection-option-for-a-user-control)

Comment: Not related, but you could do this kind of thing easily in WPF

Comment: @Ashton Woods what you meant with "not related"?

Comment: I didnt want to use wpf for lots of reasons