# How to create user control for displaying collection of other user controls in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I need to create a user control `MyTypeListControl` to display collection of objects of type `MyType` using a user controls `MyTypeDisplayControl` instance for each of those objects.

So that I could

1. add instance of `MyTypeListControl` to my WinForm, then
2. load collection of `MyType` and
3. assign it to `MyTypeListControl`'s DataSource.

In the result it should generate and show appropriate count of `MyTypeDisplayControl` instances in `MyTypeListControl`'s instance.

In case if I needed to show list of properties - equivalent would be `DataGrid` with specific fields from `MyType` assigned to specific `DataGrid`'s columns, but I want to view each `MyType` item as a user control - with more power for visual representation and functionality than `DataGrid` provides for it's rows.

Is that even possible?

[I found this SO resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000331/item-collection-option-for-a-user-control) how to create My collection type, but this is only small part of the problem solution...

Comment: Why not use a FlowLayoutPanel? Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you can display lists of your usercontrol by adding them to a FlowLayoutPanel and you can manipulate the collection easily too.

Comment: @JoshL. Can I add collection of controls to FlowLayoutPanel, similar to DataGrid.DataSource = ICollection<T>? Do You mean using Controls collection for manipulating?

Comment: @ downvoters - what's wrong with the question? It would be helpful if you would state what's wrong so I could improve ;)

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel doesn't have anything like DataGrid.DataSource, that would be something you'd have to implement yourself (or you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your UserControl's model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy (if you know how) and doesn't take so much effort as you might think in the first place (at least for a simple implementation that handles collection of less then 100 items).

So at first lets create a MyType:

```
public class MyType
{
    public static MyType Empty = new MyType(String.Empty, DateTime.MinValue);

    public MyType(string myName, DateTime myBirthday)
    {
        MyName = myName;
        MyBirthday = myBirthday;
    }

    public DateTime MyBirthday { get; private set; }

    public string MyName { get; private set; }
}
```

At next we need a MyTypeControl:

```
public partial class MyTypeControl : UserControl
{
    private MyType _MyType;
    private Label labelBirthday;
    private Label labelName;
    private Label labelSeparator;

    public MyTypeControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler MyTypeChanged;

    public MyType MyType
    {
        get { return _MyType; }
        set
        {
            if (_MyType == value)
                return;

            _MyType = value ?? MyType.Empty;
            OnMyTypeChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnMyTypeChanged(EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        UpdateVisualization();
        RaiseEvent(MyTypeChanged, eventArgs);
    }

    protected void UpdateVisualization()
    {
        SuspendLayout();

        labelName.Text = _MyType.MyName;
        labelBirthday.Text = _MyType.MyBirthday.ToString("F");
        labelBirthday.Visible = _MyType.MyBirthday != DateTime.MinValue;

        ResumeLayout();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        labelName = new Label();
        labelBirthday = new Label();
        labelSeparator = new Label();
        SuspendLayout();
        labelName.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        labelName.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        labelName.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        labelBirthday.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        labelBirthday.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        labelSeparator.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        labelSeparator.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        labelSeparator.Size = new Size(150, 2);
        Controls.Add(labelSeparator);
        Controls.Add(labelBirthday);
        Controls.Add(labelName);
        MinimumSize = new Size(0, 48);
        Name = "MyTypeControl";
        Size = new Size(150, 48);
        ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    private void RaiseEvent(EventHandler eventHandler, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var temp = eventHandler;

        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

Then comes our magically list control:

```
public class MyTypeListControl : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyType> _Items;

    public MyTypeListControl()
    {
        AutoScroll = true;
        _Items = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
        _Items.CollectionChanged += OnItemsCollectionChanged;
    }

    public Collection<MyType> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
    }

    private void OnItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateVisualization();
    }

    private void UpdateVisualization()
    {
        SuspendLayout();
        Controls.Clear();

        foreach (var item in _Items)
        {
            var control = new MyTypeControl { MyType = item, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            Controls.Add(control);
            Controls.SetChildIndex(control, 0);
        }

        ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

And now simply create the list control in your form or parent control and fill it with some meaningful values:

```
myTypeListControl.Items.Add(new MyType("Adam", DateTime.UtcNow.Add(-TimeSpan.FromDays(365 * 40))));
myTypeListControl.Items.Add(new MyType("Eva", DateTime.UtcNow.Add(-TimeSpan.FromDays(365 * 38))));
```

Comment: Thanks, this look promising - I will comment when I will check this solution out

Comment: Yes, this is working as expected! I still don't get why this question gets such a negative rating, but main is that I got a good answer! If you don't mind I will add a small update - so that the solution would accept collection of MyType-s