# creating items collection in a custom control

Tags: winforms, collections, custom-controls

I have a Custom control inheriting from Control class in my WinForm. My control contains multiple panels and other UIElements.

This is what my control is supposed to look like
[image]

There's a database panel, 
database panel contains a single checkbox only.

and there's a Server panel,
server panel contains many database panels and a single label; the header label.

And finally there's the container panel that contains all my Server panels.

I found this [Item Collection option for a User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000331/item-collection-option-for-a-user-control) but I couldn't really understand the accepted answer on it. If someone could help explain it better that would be great.

Also, if someone could just put some links for creating advanced custom controls. I've been reading all day about it and I still can't make any sense of it all. Is there a step-by-step guide for advanced custom controls?

[**Edit**]

Basically what I need is to create a custom collection within my custom control. Currently my control is built as Winform Control Library which I build and then I use in my main program later.
So in my main program, I can just drag and drop the component on my form and use it.

By default, the custom control will load with one Server that contains one database.
What I want is to be able to add/remove other databases/servers to it if I need to, in my MAIN program

I'm having trouble explaining exactly what I need because I simply do not understand how the whole custom control/items collection thing works really, and i'm sorry for that. I would really appreciate some links that explains this stuff clearly

here's my code for this control:

This code only creates my default control, but I am UNABLE to add to it. The collection property appears in my property windows but when I add items to it and click okay nothing happens.

```
public class Database : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
    public CheckBox _ckbDatabase;

    public Database()
    {
        _ckbDatabase = new CheckBox();

        this.BackColor = _pnlDatabaseBackColor;
        this.Size = _pnlDatabaseSize;
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.Height = 40;
        this.Width = 200;
        this.Location = _pnlDatabaseLocation;
        _ckbDatabase.Top = 10;
        _ckbDatabase.Left = 15;
        _ckbDatabase.TextAlign = _ckbdbTextAlignment;
        _ckbDatabase.Font = _ckbdbFont;
        _ckbDatabase.ForeColor = Color.White;

        this.Controls.Add(_ckbDatabase);

    }

    #Propterties
}

public class Server : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
    private Label _lblserver;
    private Database database;

    public Server()
    {
        _lblserver = new Label();
        database = new Database();
        this.BackColor = _pnlServerBackColor;
        this.Size = _pnlServerSize;
        this.AutoSize = false;
        _lblserver.Dock = _lblserverDock;
        _lblserver.Font = _lblsrvFont;
        _lblserver.BackColor = _lblServerBackColor;
        _lblserver.AutoSize = false;
        _lblserver.Text = SRV;

        database.Top = 35;
        database._ckbDatabase.Text = DB;

        this.Controls.Add(_lblserver);
        this.Controls.Add(database);
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public DatabaseCollection DatabaseCollection { get; set; }

    #Propterties
 }

public class ServersCollection : CollectionBase
{
    public Server this[int index]
    {
        get { return (Server)List[index]; }
    }
    public void Add(Server server)
    {
        List.Add(server);
    }
    public void Remove(Server server)
    {
        List.Remove(server);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this being done?  Are you building this control in code, as servers and DBs are discovered, or is it just a static presentation whose content never changes?

Comment: @DonBoitnott it's being built in code. I won't be needing an ObservableCollection if I'm understanding what you're hinting at.

Comment: That's more of a WPF thing anyhow, so you probably couldn't use it if you wanted to.

Comment: Since you already have the control, and you're already adding server/DBs to it, I'm not sure I understand your struggle.  Just make a class like that answer and add items to it.  It's just data.  The part about the `PropertyGrid` is irrelevant unless you need design-time support.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I edited my question, i realize I haven't really explained things well prior. Please note, that i am unable to add/remove items from my collection, my code is not working.
and i'm really sorry for being such a noob :S

Comment: @FSDaniel i'm sorry for being unclear before, I have edited my question. hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple like this:

```
public class Server {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Database> Databases { get; set; }

    public Server() {
        Databases = new List<Database>();
    }
}

public class Database {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can just add it like this:

```
        List<Server> servers = new List<Server>();

        Server serverA = new Server { Name = "Server A" };
        serverA.Databases.Add(new Database { Name = "Database 1", Enabled = true });
        serverA.Databases.Add(new Database { Name = "Database 2", Enabled = false });

        Server serverB = new Server { Name = "Server B" };
        serverB.Databases.Add(new Database { Name = "Database 1", Enabled = false });
        serverB.Databases.Add(new Database { Name = "Database 2", Enabled = false });

        servers.Add(serverA);
        servers.Add(serverB);
```

When you link to the Item Collection part it seemed like you wanted to be able to add servers and databases in design mode but then you mention you want to do it by code? If this is not what you want you need to give us more information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are mostly there.  First off, here's a more complete collection class:

```
public class ServersCollection : IEnumerable<Server>
{
    private List<Server> _servers = new List<Server>();

    public Server this[int index]
    {
        get { return _servers[index]; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Server> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var server in _servers)
            yield return server;
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    public void Add(Server server)
    {
        _servers.Add(server);
    }

    public void Remove(Server server)
    {
        //You might consider a deliberate loop to evaluate a proper match
        //Don't forget to Dispose() it first!
        _servers.Remove(server);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        for (Int32 i = _servers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            _servers[i].Dispose();
        _servers.Clear();
    }
}
```

Add an instance of the `ServersCollection` class to the container control, the one at the top level that holds server panels:

```
private ServersCollection _servers = new ServersCollection();
public ServersCollection Servers { get { return _servers; } }
```

Use that as a way for it to add `Server` controls to its own collection of controls.

Do a similar thing with the `DatabaseCollection` in the `Server` class, again so that it can add `Database` panels to its controls collection.

Then, wherever you have an instance of a control, you will also have access to the collection of what it holds:

```
myControl.Servers
//-or-
myServer.Databases
```

...allowing you to add/remove, as such:

```
myControl.Servers.Add(new Server());
//-or-
myServer.Databases.Add(new Database());
```

### Points of emphasis

Your classes are controls, but they also *own other controls*.  Proper use of the `Dispose` pattern will be crucial or you'll have memory issues throughout.

I would remove these lines, they don't matter unless you intend to add servers/DBs at form design time (i.e. fixed entries or defaults):

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public DatabaseCollection DatabaseCollection { get; set; }
```

Finally, you could (should!) take that collection class further, with overloads for `Add()` and `Remove()` that do a better job of deciding when/how/what to do based on more than an instance, e.g. by name?  You could also add another indexer to fetch by name, for instance, instead of just index (which you might not readily know).